# Multirow Pivot Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to bring back the values in a long table as wide while preserving duplicate rows:

IE: My table:

```
Colname |  ColValue  | PK
Field1  | 12         | 1
Field2  | apple      | 1
Field3  | blue       | 1
Field3  | Red        | 1
```

What I want:

```
PK | Field1| Field2 | Field3
1  |12     | apple  |blue
1  |12     | apple  |red
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make a pivot work in this situation as to do any max(colvalue) then removes the second Field 3 value. A dynamic column solution would be wonderful as I do not necessarily know the names of the fields/columns.

What I have:

```
select PK as CompPK,
                    ColName,
    Colvalue

        from test1)

        Pivot(
        max(colvalue) for ColNamein ('Field1' as Field1,'Field2' as Field2,'Field3' as Field3)
```

This returns of course just:

```
PK | Field1| Field2 | Field3
1  |12     | apple  |blue
```

I do have a time stamp column and other 'random' columns on this table.

**Edit**:

Yes. Theoretically I want all possible iterations.

Comment: What if you have multiple `field2` values?

Comment: What if when, for the same pk , field1 has 3 values, field2 has 4 values and field3 has 5 values ? Do you want to get all possible combinations of these values (3*4*5=60 rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select * from(
  Select pk, colvalue as field1
  From table1
  Where colname ='Field1'
) T1
Full Join (
  Select pk, colvalue as field2
  From table1
  Where colname ='Field2'
) T2
Using (pk)
Full join (
  Select pk, colvalue as field3
  From table1
  Where colname ='Field3'
) T3
Using (pk)
```

Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec147/3

```
| PK | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
|----|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |     12 |  apple |   blue |
|  1 |     12 |  apple |    Red |
```